# Why Riemann Mapping Theorem is not valid for $U=\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

If we take simple connected domain $U=\mathbb{C}$, in the statement of [Riemann mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem), then why is it not valid.

What is the proper justification?

Comment: The disc in not confomally equivalent to the plane, by Liouville.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there's such bijection $\phi$: Then $\phi$ is holomorphic in all $\mathbb{C}$(and bounded!). So using Lioville's Theorem $\phi$ must be a constant function hence contradiction.